# Fragment State Pager Adapter returning wrong saved bundle when change fragment position

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I can have the following fragments in a dynamic multi-step sign up form inside the view pager:

```
User wants to sign up as a Company:
     Page 0              Page  1            Page  2          Page 3
ChooseUserFragment | AddressFragment  | CompanyFragment | DataFragment |

User wants to sign up as a Client:
      Page 0              Page  1           Page  2
ChooseUserFragment | AddressFragment  | DataFragment |
```

I destroy all the fragments and recreate them  when the user change the user type option (Company -> Client or vice versa), and click to proceed to the form, but i do not want to make the user type everything again if he changes from one type to another, so I save the information typed by him in a bundle on the `onSaveInstanceState` method and recover it `onViewStateRestored`

The problem is that the bundle being passed to the `DataFragment` when I recreate the fragments comes from `CompanyFragment` not the `DataFragment` one. Is it possible to make the bundle comes from the correct fragment even changing the position of them?

Code being used to recreate the Fragments:

```
 @Override
  public int getCount() {
    if(isCreatingClientUser){
      return 3;
    } else{
      return 4;
    }
  }
@Override
  public SignUpFragment getItem(int position) {
    if(position == 0){ // Welcome screen
      return new SignUpWelcomeFragment();
    }else if(position == 1){ // Address screen
      return new SignUpAddressFragment();
    }else if(position == 2){ // Company screen or User Data
      if(isCreatingClientUser){
        return new SignUpDataFragment();
      } else{
        return new SignUpCompanyFragment();
      }
    }else if(position == 3){ // User Data screen
      return new SignUpDataFragment();
    }else{
      return null;
    }
  }

  //This is called when notifyDataSetChanged() is called
  @Override
  public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    // refresh all fragments when data set changed
    return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
  }
```

[image]